# How to use C only features in latest compilers?

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I am using codeblock 13.12 and it uses mingw (GCC 4.7 & 4.8 Series)
It supports call by reference (func1(int &a)) eventhough I am selecting C project and not CPP project. **If I am not mistaken, there is no concept of call by reference in C and everything is call by value even if it is making use of pointers.** 
My question is how to use C only features? Any settings for this? I saw that in toolchain it is using mingw32-gcc.exe for c compilations.
How to know which compiler version (Like C11, C99 etc) it is really using?

Comment: Does your IDE actually call `gcc` or `g++`? My gcc complains loudly when I try to compile `int foo(int &bar)
{
  return bar;
}
`.

Comment: I've already provided an answer, but it's entirely possible it's some weird syntax usage that happens to compile.  Can you post a minimum example of a function that is getting compiled as C, but should only validate in C++. Also, the entire command line you are using for mingw-gcc.

Comment: gcc doesn't support C++- style references as an extension in C. You must be compiling as C++.

Comment: What is the name of your source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your files with an extension of `.c`. And definitely not `.cc` or `.cpp`

Compile with `gcc` as the command line, not `g++`

And if in doubt, use the `-std=` command line parameter to force the flavor of C you want (e.g. `-std=C90`, `-std=C99`, or even `-std=C11` ).  There's also `-ansi`.

Also, a cheap and dirty way to validate if your code is getting compiled as C and not C++ is to add this block of code within your source code.  If it's C++, then the compiler will generate an error.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
int compile_time_assert[-1];
#endif
```

Comment: By changing file name to .c it worked. I got error message "expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token". When using .cpp, the compilation command is mingw32-g++.exe -Wall  -IC:\Temp -c C:\Temp\temp.cpp -o C:\Temp\temp.o  and when using .c extention, it is mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall  -IC:\Temp -c C:\Temp\temp.c -o C:\Temp\temp.o